# Ugly dark leaf stains on a concrete patio - any modern 2015-ish way to treat them?

Tags: staining, patio

I know about the [what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-and-prevent-leaf-stains-on-concrete-pavers](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1876/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-and-prevent-leaf-stains-on-concrete-pavers) question and its answers, and I'm trying to revive it and continue the search for the perfect answer.

I'm in a similar situation - a new patio was paved by concrete pavers from Cambridge (I didn't know they were porous) and I've left wet leaves on it for a couple of weeks (I didn't know about tannin stains).

However the question above is from **2010**... Are there any recent achievements in chemistry, which will allow me to remove these tannin stains, or at least to decrease their dark color intensity? I have found references about "Genesis 950" and tea tree oil - do they really help?

**UPDATE**: I'm emphasizing that the question [what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-and-prevent-leaf-stains-on-concrete-pavers](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1876/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-and-prevent-leaf-stains-on-concrete-pavers), mentioned in the beginning of my question and also pointed out as a duplicate, is **five-years old**, and so doesn't contain most recent information about various chemicals, which I don't know about, but may be somebody here does. I've also given two examples of agents, which weren't discussed in this question.

Additionally, it looks harsh to me to point me to the question, which I myself have addressed in the beginning of my question and pretend this question solves all my problems (it doesn't). I've already tried some ways to remove these stains (dishwasher detergent, OxiClean), but they are still there.

Comment: Why downvote? Please explain...

Comment: I sorta doubt that anything new and worthewhile for this purpose has appeared in the past 15 years.

Comment: The proper way to draw new attention and potentially fresh answers to an old question is to [post a bounty](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).

Comment: @NiallC. - "please edit this question to explain how it is different" - that's what I've already done *before* you've closed my question.

Comment: @NiallC. - from Wiki page about Stack Overflow: "Jeff Atwood stated in 2010 that duplicate questions are not seen as a problem but rather they constitute an advantage if such additional questions drive extra traffic to the site by multiplying relevant keyword hits in search engines" (please see here if you don't believe me - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if any new or different cleaners have appeared since the 2010 question. I think the tried and true cleaners on the market presently will remove most stains in existence. For cleaning un-sealed and porous concrete there are several cleaners that should work to easily remove the leaf stains. Starting with the least aggressive to the strongest: there is a stain removing product that is poured onto the dried stained surface that will solidify as it extracts the stain, "Pour n' Restore" (something like that). I've never used it myself and only heard mild reviews. The second product is "Krud Kutter" which I've found to work very well on any stain to be removed. It is best to agitate it with a scrub brush. TSP (tri-sodium phosphate) is what most contractors and DIY-ers go to when cleaning surfaces. Remove from glass surfaces or it will mark it and rinse with water. The last and most assured way to dissolve any stain from concrete will have to be concocted at home since it is no longer available on the open market. Wet the surface to be cleaned. After covering yourself with protective gear, scrub the surface with a 10% solution of hydrochloric acid and rinse with water. The other suggestion is to power wash it with a pressure washer. One of the last two ideas should, at the very least, fade the discoloration. Otherwise the pavers can be painted or stained.