# Leaf stains on fresh concrete driveway not sealed yet

Tags: concrete

My driveway was poured when I was on vacation and leaves fell on it and they made a black mark I believe it's called tar leaf in about 20 places in the driveway and before they come and seal it I wanted to know how to get it off before the winter comes and the Salt destroys it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to remove and prevent leaf stains on concrete pavers?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1876/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-and-prevent-leaf-stains-on-concrete-pavers)

Comment: The pavers are little bit different this is a california-style driveway with a brush stroke so on the rough spots the leaves have made marks that really need to come off before he seals it I understand the sun will fade in time the winter is less than 2 months away and he's thinking we shouldn't seal it until the leaves marks are gone. and he didn't see like at the beginning once he finished like within 2 hours because he was doing three of my neighbors houses all in the same month... we all just figured to get it done at the very end

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Rather than put lots of details in a comment, it's best to edit the information right into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Tar leaf, simply known  as tar, is caused from the organic pigments that give leaves and pine cones their color get embedded in the micro-pores and small voids on the surface of the concrete. They can be hard to remove without a good detergent and some scrubbing action. The best detergent to use is one with bleaching action or ammonia. Typically detergents designed to remove organic stains (blood, food stains, etc.) work best. OxiClean is one example. Granular detergents offer an added benefit, because they provide additional friction when you scrub the surface.

Here are the basic steps to follow:

Use a pressure washer to remove all solid leaf matter and debris from the concrete.

Apply a household detergent (as recommended above) to damp concrete. Let it sit and wet out for a few minutes.

Scrub vigorously with a stiff broom or scrub brush.

Rinse the concrete with water until you remove all the soap.

If this procedure doesn't completely remove the stains, repeat the process.

[image]

Comment: I don't think I would chose to use a pressure washer on fresh concrete. A weak Muriatic acid and water solution would etch the stain off. but the detergent may be the best method but requires more physical labor.

Comment: I have different nozzles for the pressure washer and the weaker one has been fine.buy I do understand your point thank you..I have the dry detergent and bleach liquid and crystals and I will try all if I have to before they come and seal it..thx again

Answer (score 1):

Tannin , get used to it. Unless you are going to paint it , the concrete will weather. Tannin stains will come and go. I use a 50:50 bleach/ water and a garden sprayer every coupe years to make my wife happy.